# Rails app deployment into Heroku, build issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, sass

I'm new to the whole ruby on rails development environment, and I'm struggling to deploy an existing app onto Heroku.

I have spoken to Heroku support and they have failed to continue to address my issue, which is disappointing. Now the specific problem relates to the following terminal command:

`$ git push heroku master`

This is my output (I will start from the position where it starts to go wrong!):

```
remote:        Installing turbolinks 2.5.3
remote:        Installing rails 4.2.0
remote:        Your bundle is complete!
remote:        Gems in the groups development and test were not installed.
remote:        It was installed into ./vendor/bundle
remote:        Post-install message from rdoc:
remote:        Depending on your version of ruby, you may need to install ruby rdoc/ri data:
remote:        <= 1.8.6 : unsupported
remote:        = 1.8.7 : gem install rdoc-data; rdoc-data --install
remote:        = 1.9.1 : gem install rdoc-data; rdoc-data --install
remote:        >= 1.9.2 : nothing to do! Yay!
remote:        Bundle completed (39.87s)
remote:        Cleaning up the bundler cache.
remote: -----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
remote:        Running: rake assets:precompile
remote:        I, [2015-03-18T17:04:43.818368 #1194]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_02a03f7daac8fa16dbf45f752b79f4cc/public/assets/FontAwesome-838af52e382b27dca33a344726a9ec67.otf
remote:        I, [2015-03-18T17:04:43.820455 #1194]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_02a03f7daac8fa16dbf45f752b79f4cc/public/assets/fontawesome-webfont-429acacb01a51b0738d8b0c6dcee0fc4.eot
remote:        I, [2015-03-18T17:04:43.823090 #1194]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_02a03f7daac8fa16dbf45f752b79f4cc/public/assets/fontawesome-webfont-9c8db592bac7eb9e7ef1b0c464140fa5.svg
remote:        I, [2015-03-18T17:04:43.825779 #1194]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_02a03f7daac8fa16dbf45f752b79f4cc/public/assets/fontawesome-webfont-9bf0604ed1778de864df7e69a3348217.ttf
remote:        I, [2015-03-18T17:04:43.827790 #1194]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_02a03f7daac8fa16dbf45f752b79f4cc/public/assets/fontawesome-webfont-ff4168b9c4bf807dd42d15ce204cb1ad.woff
remote:        I, [2015-03-18T17:04:49.756561 #1194]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_02a03f7daac8fa16dbf45f752b79f4cc/public/assets/application-cba6abf49f8c4efcc9f21fa8851e620a.js
remote:        rake aborted!
remote:        Sass::SyntaxError: Invalid CSS after "": expected keyframes selector (e.g. 10%), was "0"
remote:        (in /tmp/build_02a03f7daac8fa16dbf45f752b79f4cc/app/assets/stylesheets/application.css)
remote:        (sass):11234
remote:        /tmp/build_02a03f7daac8fa16dbf45f752b79f4cc/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.13/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:1165:in `expected'
remote:        /tmp/build_02a03f7daac8fa16dbf45f752b79f4cc/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.13/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:1101:in `expected'
remote:        /tmp/build_02a03f7daac8fa16dbf45f752b79f4cc/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.13/lib/sass/scss/parser.rb:1081:in `expr!'
remote:        /tmp/build_02a03f7daac8fa16dbf45f752b79f4cc/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.13/lib/sass/scss/static_parser.rb:46:in `parse_keyframes_selector'
remote:        /tmp/build_02a03f7daac8fa16dbf45f752b79f4cc/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.13/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:412:in `visit_rule'
remote:        /tmp/build_02a03f7daac8fa16dbf45f752b79f4cc/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.13/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:36:in `visit'
remote:        /tmp/build_02a03f7daac8fa16dbf45f752b79f4cc/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.13/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:158:in `block in visit'
remote:        /tmp/build_02a03f7daac8fa16dbf45f752b79f4cc/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.13/lib/sass/stack.rb:79:in `block in with_base'
remote:        /tmp/build_02a03f7daac8fa16dbf45f752b79f4cc/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.13/lib/sass/stack.rb:115:in `with_frame'
remote:        /tmp/build_02a03f7daac8fa16dbf45f752b79f4cc/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.13/lib/sass/stack.rb:79:in `with_base'
remote:        /tmp/build_02a03f7daac8fa16dbf45f752b79f4cc/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.13/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:158:in `visit'
remote:        /tmp/build_02a03f7daac8fa16dbf45f752b79f4cc/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.13/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:501:in `block (2 levels) in visit_directive'
remote:        /tmp/build_02a03f7daac8fa16dbf45f752b79f4cc/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.13/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:501:in `map'
remote:        /tmp/build_02a03f7daac8fa16dbf45f752b79f4cc/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.13/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:501:in `block in visit_directive'
remote:        /tmp/build_02a03f7daac8fa16dbf45f752b79f4cc/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.13/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:179:in `with_environment
remote:        /tmp/build_02a03f7daac8fa16dbf45f752b79f4cc/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.13/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:500:in `visit_directive'
remote:        /tmp/build_02a03f7daac8fa16dbf45f752b79f4cc/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.13/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:36:in `visit'
remote:        /tmp/build_02a03f7daac8fa16dbf45f752b79f4cc/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.13/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:158:in `block in visit'
remote:        /tmp/build_02a03f7daac8fa16dbf45f752b79f4cc/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.13/lib/sass/stack.rb:79:in `block in with_base'
remote:        /tmp/build_02a03f7daac8fa16dbf45f752b79f4cc/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.13/lib/sass/stack.rb:115:in `with_frame'
remote:        /tmp/build_02a03f7daac8fa16dbf45f752b79f4cc/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.13/lib/sass/stack.rb:79:in `with_base'
remote:        /tmp/build_02a03f7daac8fa16dbf45f752b79f4cc/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.13/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:158:in `visit'
remote:        /tmp/build_02a03f7daac8fa16dbf45f752b79f4cc/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.13/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:52:in `block in visit_children'
remote:        /tmp/build_02a03f7daac8fa16dbf45f752b79f4cc/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.13/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:52:in `map'
remote:        /tmp/build_02a03f7daac8fa16dbf45f752b79f4cc/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.13/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:52:in `visit_children'
remote:        /tmp/build_02a03f7daac8fa16dbf45f752b79f4cc/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.13/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:167:in `block in visit_children'
remote:        /tmp/build_02a03f7daac8fa16dbf45f752b79f4cc/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.13/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:179:in `with_environment
remote:        /tmp/build_02a03f7daac8fa16dbf45f752b79f4cc/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.13/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:166:in `visit_children'
remote:        /tmp/build_02a03f7daac8fa16dbf45f752b79f4cc/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.13/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:36:in `block in visit'
remote:        /tmp/build_02a03f7daac8fa16dbf45f752b79f4cc/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.13/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:186:in `visit_root'
remote:        /tmp/build_02a03f7daac8fa16dbf45f752b79f4cc/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.13/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:36:in `visit'
remote:        /tmp/build_02a03f7daac8fa16dbf45f752b79f4cc/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.13/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:157:in `visit'
remote:        /tmp/build_02a03f7daac8fa16dbf45f752b79f4cc/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.13/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:8:in `visit'
remote:        /tmp/build_02a03f7daac8fa16dbf45f752b79f4cc/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.13/lib/sass/tree/root_node.rb:36:in `css_tree'
remote:        /tmp/build_02a03f7daac8fa16dbf45f752b79f4cc/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.13/lib/sass/tree/root_node.rb:20:in `render'
remote:        /tmp/build_02a03f7daac8fa16dbf45f752b79f4cc/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.4.13/lib/sass/engine.rb:268:in `render'
remote:        /tmp/build_02a03f7daac8fa16dbf45f752b79f4cc/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.3/lib/sprockets/sass_compressor.rb:24:in `evaluate'
remote:        /tmp/build_02a03f7daac8fa16dbf45f752b79f4cc/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/tilt-1.4.1/lib/tilt/template.rb:103:in `render'
remote:        /tmp/build_02a03f7daac8fa16dbf45f752b79f4cc/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.3/lib/sprockets/context.rb:197:in `block in evaluate'
remote:        /tmp/build_02a03f7daac8fa16dbf45f752b79f4cc/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.3/lib/sprockets/context.rb:194:in `each'
remote:        /tmp/build_02a03f7daac8fa16dbf45f752b79f4cc/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.3/lib/sprockets/context.rb:194:in `evaluate'
remote:        /tmp/build_02a03f7daac8fa16dbf45f752b79f4cc/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.3/lib/sprockets/bundled_asset.rb:25:in `initialize'
remote:        /tmp/build_02a03f7daac8fa16dbf45f752b79f4cc/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:377:in `new'
remote:        /tmp/build_02a03f7daac8fa16dbf45f752b79f4cc/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:377:in `build_asset'
remote:        /tmp/build_02a03f7daac8fa16dbf45f752b79f4cc/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.3/lib/sprockets/index.rb:94:in `block in build_asset'
remote:        /tmp/build_02a03f7daac8fa16dbf45f752b79f4cc/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.3/lib/sprockets/caching.rb:58:in `cache_asset'
remote:        /tmp/build_02a03f7daac8fa16dbf45f752b79f4cc/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.3/lib/sprockets/index.rb:93:in `build_asset'
remote:        /tmp/build_02a03f7daac8fa16dbf45f752b79f4cc/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:287:in `find_asset'
remote:        /tmp/build_02a03f7daac8fa16dbf45f752b79f4cc/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.3/lib/sprockets/index.rb:61:in `find_asset'
remote:        /tmp/build_02a03f7daac8fa16dbf45f752b79f4cc/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.3/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:211:in `block in find_asset
remote:        /tmp/build_02a03f7daac8fa16dbf45f752b79f4cc/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.3/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:257:in `benchmark'
remote:        /tmp/build_02a03f7daac8fa16dbf45f752b79f4cc/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.3/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:210:in `find_asset'
remote:        /tmp/build_02a03f7daac8fa16dbf45f752b79f4cc/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.3/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:119:in `block in compile'
remote:        /tmp/build_02a03f7daac8fa16dbf45f752b79f4cc/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.3/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:118:in `each'
remote:        /tmp/build_02a03f7daac8fa16dbf45f752b79f4cc/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.3/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:118:in `compile'
remote:        /tmp/build_02a03f7daac8fa16dbf45f752b79f4cc/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.2.4/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:70:in `block (3 levels) in define'
remote:        /tmp/build_02a03f7daac8fa16dbf45f752b79f4cc/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.3/lib/rake/sprocketstask.rb:146:in `with_logger'
remote:        /tmp/build_02a03f7daac8fa16dbf45f752b79f4cc/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.2.4/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:69:in `block (2 levels) in define'
remote:        Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile
remote:        (See full trace by running task with --trace)
remote:  !
remote:  !     Precompiling assets failed.
remote:  !
remote: 
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app
remote: 
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to quiet-springs-8146.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/quiet-springs-8146.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/quiet-springs-8146.git'
```

What does this mean exactly, and what would be the potential solutions to such an error?

Any help would be warmly appreciated!

All that the application.css file contains is my flash stylings (for an user authentication/signup/login app): Flash is just the class which contains these elements (incidentally it does work, the flash messages do appear to be droid sans and 13px etc within my browser).

```
.flash {
    color: #363636;
    font-family: 'Droid Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
}
```

FOA: main.css.scss

```
/* GLOBAL CSS
 -------------------------------------------------- */

body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    font-family: Lora,"Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    background-color: #000000;
}

html, body, #container {height: 100%;}

body > #container {height: auto; min-height: 5%;}

html {
    width: 100%;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
    margin: 0 0 35px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: 'Roboto',"Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
}

p {
    font-family: 'Droid Sans', sans-serif;
    margin: 0 0 25px;
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 1.5;
}

@media(min-width:768px) {
    p {
        margin: 0 0 35px;
        font-size: 20px;
        line-height: 1.6;
    }
}

a {
    color: #562cd4;
    -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}

a:hover,
a:focus {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #5913d1;
}

.light {
    font-weight: 400;
}

/* CUSTOMIZE THE NAVBAR
 -------------------------------------------------- */

.navbar-custom {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,.3);
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: Montserrat,"Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    background-color: #000000;
}

.navbar-custom .navbar-brand {
    font-weight: 600;
}

.navbar-custom .navbar-brand:focus {
    outline: 0;
}

.navbar-custom .navbar-brand .navbar-toggle {
    padding: 4px 6px;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #ffffff;
}

.navbar-custom .navbar-brand .navbar-toggle:focus,
.navbar-custom .navbar-brand .navbar-toggle:active {
    outline: 0;
}

.navbar-custom a {
    color: #ffffff;
}

.navbar-custom .nav li a {
    -webkit-transition: background .3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: background .3s ease-in-out;
    transition: background .3s ease-in-out;
}

.navbar-custom .nav li a:hover {
    outline: 0;
    color: rgba(255,255,255,.8);
    background-color: transparent;
}

.navbar-custom .nav li a:focus,
.navbar-custom .nav li a:active {
    outline: 0;
    background-color: transparent;
}

.navbar-custom .nav li.active {
    outline: 0;
}

.navbar-custom .nav li.active a {
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.3);
}

.navbar-custom .nav li.active a:hover {
    color: #ffffff;
}

@media(min-width:768px) {
    .navbar-custom {
        padding: 20px 0;
        border-bottom: 0;
        letter-spacing: 1px;
        background: 0 0;
        -webkit-transition: background .5s ease-in-out,padding .5s ease-in-out;
        -moz-transition: background .5s ease-in-out,padding .5s ease-in-out;
        transition: background .5s ease-in-out,padding .5s ease-in-out;
    }

    .navbar-custom.top-nav-collapse {
        padding: 0;
        border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,.3);
        background: #000;
    }
}

#fafa_inline {
    display: inline;
    color: #ffffff;
}

/* CUSTOMIZE THE JUMBOTRON
 -------------------------------------------------- */

.jumbotron {
    background-image:url('https://dl-web.dropbox.com/get/astroboxio_vela_mosaic_background.gif?_subject_uid=209608449&w=AABTZ4DArPvunSTYalnTRheoQM2Kb8Y1wPnlMZEl1Adfhg');
    height: 570px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover
}

.jumbotron .title {
    text-align: center;
}

.jumbotron_image {
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.jumbotron .container {
    position: relative;
    top:10px;
}

.jumbotron astrobox {
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 110px;
    font-family: 'Basic', sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    display: inline;
}

.jumbotron io {
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 48px;
    font-family: 'Lobster', sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    display: inline;
}

.jumbotron .container p {
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 4px;
}

.jumbotron_paragraphs .jumbotron_image_ras {
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.jumbotron_paragraphs .jumbotron_image_dotastronomy {
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

/* CUSTOMIZE THE CAROUSEL
-------------------------------------------------- */
.carousel {
    background-color: #000000;
    height: 500px;
    margin-bottom: 60px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.carousel-caption {
    z-index: 10;
}

.carousel-caption h1 {
    z-index: 10;
}

.carousel-caption p {
    z-index: 10;
}

.carousel .item {
    height: 500px;
    background-color: #000000;
}
.carousel-inner > .item > img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    min-width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
}

.intro .intro-body {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.intro .intro-body .brand-heading {
    font-size: 40px;
}

.intro .intro-body .intro-text {
    font-size: 18px;
}

@media(min-width:668px) {
    .intro {
        height: 100%;
        padding: 0;
    }

    .intro .intro-body .brand-heading {
        font-size: 100px;
    }

    .intro .intro-body .intro-text {
        font-size: 26px;
    }
}

/* CUSTOMIZE NEIGHBORHOOD-GUIDES
 -------------------------------------------------- */

.neighborhood-guides {
    background-color: #000000;
    height: 490px;
}

.studio_pipeline {
    background-size: 60%;
}

.studio_pipeline h2 {
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #562cd4;
    background-size: 100%;
    padding: 0.5cm;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: initial;
    border-top: 1px solid #dbdbdb;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #dbdbdb;
}

.studio_pipeline p {
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #000000;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-family: 'Droid Sans', sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 13px;
}

.thumbnail {
    background-color: #000000;
    border: 0;
}

.thumbnail_description {
    background-color: #000000;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
}

.thumbnail_description h1 {
    background-color: #000000;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-family: 'Droid Sans', sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 30px;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    letter-spacing: 0;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
}

.thumbnail_description p {
    background-color: #000000;
    color: #363636;
    font-family: 'Droid Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    letter-spacing: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.thumbnail img {
    background-color: #000000;
    padding: 20px;
    opacity: 0.85;
    border-radius: 100%;
}

.thumbnail img:hover {
    background-color: #000000;
    opacity: 1.0;
}

.btn-circle {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-left: 48.8%;
    padding: 8px;
    border: 1px solid #ffffff;
    border-radius: 100%!important;
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #ffffff;
    background: 0 0;
    -webkit-transition: background .3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: background .3s ease-in-out;
    transition: background .3s ease-in-out;
}

.btn-circle:hover,
.btn-circle:focus {
    outline: 0;
    color: #ffffff;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,.1);
}

.btn-circle i.animated {
    -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 1s;
    -moz-transition-property: -moz-transform;
    -moz-transition-duration: 1s;
}

.btn-circle:hover i.animated {
    -webkit-animation-name: pulse;
    -moz-animation-name: pulse;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
    -moz-animation-duration: 1.5s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
    -moz-animation-timing-function: linear;
}

@-webkit-keyframes pulse {    
    0 {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1);
        transform: scale(1);
    }

    50% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
        transform: scale(1.2);
    }

    100% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1);
        transform: scale(1);
    }
}

@-moz-keyframes pulse {    
    0 {
        -moz-transform: scale(1);
        transform: scale(1);
    }

    50% {
        -moz-transform: scale(1.2);
        transform: scale(1.2);
    }

    100% {
        -moz-transform: scale(1);
        transform: scale(1);
    }
}

.content-section {
    padding-top: 100px;
}

.about {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 50px 0;
    color: #ffffff;
    background: url(../assets/images/downloads-bg.jpg) no-repeat center center scroll;
    background-color: #000;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
}

#map {
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    margin-top: 100px;
}

@media(min-width:767px) {
    .content-section {
        padding-top: 250px;
    }

    .carousel-caption p {
        margin-bottom: 20px;
        font-size: 21px;
        line-height: 1.4;
    }

    .about {
        padding: 100px 0;
    }

    #map {
        height: 400px;
        margin-top: 250px;
    }
}

.btn {
    border-radius: 0;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: 'Roboto',"Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 400;
    -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
    transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
}

.btn-default {
    border: 1px solid #ffffff;
    color: #ffffff;
    border-radius: 20%!important;
    background-color: transparent;
}

.btn-default:hover,
.btn-default:focus {
    border: 1px solid #ffffff;
    outline: 0;
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #562cd4;
}

ul.banner-social-buttons {
    margin-top: 0;
}

@media(max-width:1199px) {
    ul.banner-social-buttons {
        margin-top: 15px;
    }
}

@media(max-width:767px) {
    ul.banner-social-buttons li {
        display: block;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
        padding: 0;
    }

    ul.banner-social-buttons li:last-child {
        margin-bottom: 0;
    }
}

/* CUSTOMIZE THE STICKY BAR FOOTER
 -------------------------------------------------- */

.sticky-bar {
    background: #000000;
    bottom: 0;
    color: #D3D3D3;
    font-weight: 300;
    left: 0;
    margin: 0;
    opacity: 0.9;
    padding: 0em;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    z-index:99999;}

.sticky-bar-inner {
    margin:0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    width:100%;
    background-color: #D3D3D3;
    padding: 2px;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-size: 11px;
    color: #000000;
}

.sticky-bar-inner p {
    margin:0 auto;
    padding: 2px;
    text-align: center;
    width:100%;
    font-size: 11px;

}

#footerlist {
    padding-left:0;
}

#footerlist li {
    display: inline;
    list-style-type: none;
}

::-moz-selection {
    text-shadow: none;
    background: #fcfcfc;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,.2);
}

::selection {
    text-shadow: none;
    background: #fcfcfc;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,.2);
}

img::selection {
    background: 0 0;
}

img::-moz-selection {
    background: 0 0;
}

body {
    webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(255,255,255,.2);
}
```

Comment: Looks like a syntax error in a stylesheet.

Comment: @NickM The stylesheet in question (application.css) is now included in the script. Any points?

Comment: Can you post the stylesheet?

Comment: @NickM done. It's literally one css class selector that could be written on the back of a postage stamp! :)

Comment: Weird. Sorry, I don't think I can help. Best of luck

Comment: No worries man. Very weird! Never had this before.

Comment: Does it work if you clear out that style sheet? Might be worth a shot just to make sure that's the problem.

Comment: @NickM I've commented it out: still doesn't work. Should I clear it entirely?

Comment: @MichaelRoberts Can you please post the actual application.css

Comment: @Almaron I have, and it is just one css selector. It's at the bottom of the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the error message, first thing I notice is the extension of your file `/app/assets/stylesheets/application.css`

*Rename*

`app/assets/stylesheets/application.css`

To

`app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.scss` (**NOTE** the added extension `.scss`)

This way `sass` gem can actually preprocess your stylesheets.

**UPDATE**

Use the option `-a` while committing the changes to `git`

`git commit -am <commit message>`

This option will automatically stage files that have been modified and/or deleted. In your case `app/assets/stylesheets/application.css` would be treated as deleted and `app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.scss` as newly added.

> Sass::SyntaxError: Invalid CSS after "": expected keyframes selector
>   (e.g. 10%), was "0" remote: (in
>   /tmp/build_365c7241bf197a8f84d0ec4a70ddd900/app/assets/stylesheets/main.css.scss‌​:399)

To fix the above error, in `app/assets/stylesheets/main.css.scss`, you need to update the following code (use `0%` instead of `0`):

```
@-webkit-keyframes pulse { 
    // Use 0% and not 0    
    0% { 
        -webkit-transform: scale(1);
        transform: scale(1);
    }

   //...
}

@-moz-keyframes pulse {    
    // Use 0% and not 0  
    0% {
        -moz-transform: scale(1);
        transform: scale(1);
    }

    //...
}
```

Comment: Apologies, how would I commit these changes using git...? I've tried git commit -m "css.scss changes" but that is not working for some reason...

Comment: @MichaelRoberts Read the UPDATE section in my answer, that would give you some clue.

Comment: I'm a little closer, I'm now receiving this error: Sprockets::CircularDependencyError: /tmp/build_3e9bf343ae16a2bad868bd4018d24427/app/assets/stylesheets/application.css has already been required

Comment: Passed this error, I'm now getting this: rake aborted!
remote:        Sass::SyntaxError: Invalid CSS after "": expected keyframes selector (e.g. 10%), was "0"
remote:        (in /tmp/build_365c7241bf197a8f84d0ec4a70ddd900/app/assets/stylesheets/main.css.scss:399)

Comment: @MichaelRoberts It seems like you have Invalid CSS in `main.css.scss`. Please share the code from `main.css.scss` on and around line 399. Add it as an Update in the question.

Comment: Done. Specific to that it is this section that is "invalid"" @-webkit-keyframes pulse {    
    0 {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1);
        transform: scale(1);
    }

    50% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
        transform: scale(1.2);
    }

    100% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1);
        transform: scale(1);
    }
}

Comment: @MichaelRoberts That's just it. :) I updated my answer with the findings.

Comment: Just updating my answer. Do you have twitter at all...you seem like you know what you're doing and I need to hire someone for a development project.

Comment: @MichaelRoberts Thanks for the offer! May be in future, we can get connected via GitHub or LinkedIn(links on my profile).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to change application.css. You can create new file: 
ex:

```
custom.css.scss
```

If you using bootstrap, add bootstrap rails to Gemfile and import following lines to custom.css.scss:

```
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
```

Run commands:

```
$ bundle install
$ git push heroku master -f
```

If you can't using bootstrap in heroku:
Open config/environments/production.rb and edit following line:

```
config.assets.compile = false
```

to

```
config.assets.compile = true
```

Push again to github and heroku.